# Найти наименьший положительный элемент последовательности Java

Tags: java

Столкнулся с небольшой задачкой, к которой пока не понимаю решения.
Нужно найти наименьший положительный элемент последовательности[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду рад любым советам.

```
ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
array.add(-99);
array.add(-99);
array.add(-99);

int i=array.size();

do {
array.add(array.get(i)+array.get(i-1)+array.get(i-2)+200);
i++;
} while (array.get(i)>0);
//
for (int j = 0; j < array.size(); j++) {
    System.out.print(array.get(j) + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте массив или ArrayList, заполните три первых элемента, как указано справа, затем заполняйте в цикле следующие элементы согласно рекуррентному соотношению, описанному слева.

Остановитесь, когда три элемента будут положительными, дальше идти смысла нет.

Comment: Я недавно начал учить Java, пока не очень получается)
Я добавил то что сделал в вопрос, не могли бы вы глянуть?

Comment: Ну примерно так и можно. Только `i=array.size() - 1;` и  после остановки вывести array.get(i), весь массив ни к чему.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, разобрался